# Making a fat jar file and adding dependencies - Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libgdx, kryonet

I am using the Eclipse IDE, using Kryonet and LibGDX libraries.

I am currently trying to make a fat jar file - making kryonet a dependency.

How would I make a big jar file?

Here is my build.gradle file

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["../core/assets"]

project.ext.mainClassName = "uk.ac.aston.teamproj.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../core/assets")

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}


dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-desktop"
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How can I make a big jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the "Shadow" gradle plugin to make fat jars, it makes the process a lot simpler.

You can find detailed instructions on how to use it [here](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/getting-started/)

If you want an executable jar don't forget to specify the MainClass attribute. Here's an example of usage:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        shadowVersion = "5.2.0"
        mainClassName = "com.yourapp.>>>CLASS_NAME_CONTAINING_YOUR_MAIN_METHOD_GOES_HERE<<<"
    }

    // Repositories for build scripts
    repositories {
        // Maven
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // Sonatype repositories
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }

    // Dependencies for build scripts
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:$shadowVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class": project.mainClassName,
        )
    }
}
```

This will add the following to your build:

- Adds a `shadowJar` task to the project.
- Adds a `shadow` configuration to the project.
- Configures the `shadowJar` task to include all sources from the project's main sourceSet.
- Configures the `shadowJar` task to bundle all dependencies from the `runtimeClasspath` configuration.
- Configures the `classifier` attribute of the `shadowJar` task to be 'all' .
- Configures the `shadowJar` task to generate a Manifest with:

  - Inheriting all configuration from the standard jar task.
  - Adds a `Class-Path` attribute to the `Manifest` that appends `all dependencies` from the shadow configuration

The `shadowJar` task will build the fat jar, optionally it will be executable if you specified a Main-Class attribute for the manifest in the `jar` configuration, as I did in the above example.